# (Python3) string's (real) length/width

Tags: python-3.x, string-length

Let's say I want to "underline" a string with dots with Python3 :

Everything's fine with ASCII characters : I get the length with `len(mystring)` and I write as much dots as needed. Here is an example with a string whose length is 8 :

```
mystring
........
```

But with non-ASCII characters `len(mystring)` doesn't return the result I need; e.g. len("列島") is 2, but I need 4 dots to underline the string :

```
列島
....
```

How can I get the correct result ? Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: In the general case, the width of each glyph can be different, and its display width can only be found by querying the rendering engine for the width in a particular font at a particular size.

Answer (score 0):

... [unicodedata.east_asian_width()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unicodedata.html) does the trick.

See by example [this implementation](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@b@l@blockdiag-1.2.4@src@blockdiag@imagedraw@utils@__init__.py/71/unicodedata.east_asian_width).

Comment: I don't seem to get the expected 5 for the string "Z̹͎̰̀A̴̼͙͚ͅL͔̫̭̺͙̳̲͟G̻̘̰̤̤͟ͅǪ̞͙̗" :)

Comment: Nope. You're asking "get the width of this string", and I'm asking "in what units?", to which you can answer "in multiples of width of a dot". I can only answer that if you specify a font (see @tripleee's comment).